# Merging Rows with additional row in mysql

Tags: mysql

The output of my actual mysql query look like this:

```
name      type    desc         timestamp
xyz       start   desc1        2018-07-24 09:03:15
xyz       end     desc1        2018-07-24 10:31:57
xyz       start   desc2        2018-07-24 10:33:16
xyz       end     desc2        2018-07-24 10:53:27
zyx       start   desc1        2018-07-24 10:09:19
zyx       end     desc1        2018-07-24 10:24:34
```

I would like to merge start and end for each name and desc into one row. Something like this:

```
name       desc         start(timestamp)        end(timestamp)
xyz        desc1        2018-07-24 09:03:15     2018-07-24 10:31:57
xyz        desc2        2018-07-24 10:33:16     2018-07-24 10:53:27
```

I'm not a big expert in mysql so maybe someone can help me

Comment: Please add your efforts to solve the problem.

Comment: Please show actual timestamps instead of `xxx`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just added the timestamps

Comment: damn sqlfiddle.com is down no easy way to covert the text formatted table into SQL statements

Comment: @RaymondNijland Use Rextester :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Rextester doesn't have a ascii data table to SQL statements generator?

Comment: Ooh...I didn't know SQL Fiddle had that.  Yeah...I usually also feel too lazy to transcribe everything.

Comment: There is no internal order to your MySQL table, and I don't think we can generate the output you showed based just on this table.  We would need another column which can be used to form groups.

Answer (score 1):

A co-related subquery might be the easy method to get the results you need.

Remember to alias correctly really important with co-related subqueries.

```
SELECT 
    table1.name,
    table1.desc,
    table1.timestamp AS 'start(timestamp)', 
    (SELECT table2.timestamp
     FROM table AS table2
     WHERE table1.timestamp < table2.timestamp
       AND table1.name = table2.name
       AND table2.type = 'end'
     ORDER BY table2.timestamp ASC
     LIMIT 1) AS 'end(timestamp)'
FROM    
    table AS table1
WHERE
    table1.type = 'start'
    AND table1.name = 'xyz'
ORDER BY 
    table1.timestamp ASC
```

p.s to optimize this a `index(name, type, timestamp)` is needed.

Comment: This query [doesn't generate the expected results](http://rextester.com/FPB68603).  Ignore that it is for SQL Server (I was trying out a gaps and islands query).  Look closely at the OP's data; you'll see that it makes no sense.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen your right ... this query is missing `AND
       table1.name = table2.name
     AND
       table2.type = 'end'`  then it works http://rextester.com/TEZ58857

Comment: OK but why only two records in the output instead of three?

Comment: The expected output off the topicstarter also show two records?  @TimBiegeleisen WHERE filter on name = 'xyz'.. if you didn't notice the example data has two names 'xyz' and 'zyx'

Comment: Didn't see that +1.  This is almost a gaps and islands problem from what I can tell.  Good that you found a solution without having to use analytic functions.

Comment: "Good that you found a solution without having to use analytic functions. " Well "solution" iám not a huge fan off using co-related subqueries in MySQL they tend to optimize and scale badly on large tables. .@TimBiegeleisen Besides i see more solutions for this problem involving user variables (simulating `ROW_NUMBER()`) and  `GROUP_CONCAT`